# Regarding powershell profiles, what is the 'Current Host' referring to in 'Current User, Current Host'

Tags: powershell

I'm learning how to set up a PowerShell profile. There are four types each with a description of 'x User, x Host' (x being Current or All). I am having trouble understanding what/who the Host is.

I know that the Profile is a script that runs when PowerShell starts, and I'm assuming 'Current User' is whoever is logged on, whereas an 'All Users' account would take precedence and load up first.

But no idea what Host is...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "host" is the application currently hosting your PowerShell session - in `powershell.exe` that would be the `ConsoleHost` application, whereas PowerShell ISE would have a different host

Comment: Just use `Get-Host` in script or at prompt to obtain your current host

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please see path of different profiles for different host
[image]

[image]

[image]

**How profile script work for different host and different users example**

Suppose you want to change your prompt for all users to `PS C:\Temp>`  instead of default `PS C:\Users\Username>` in all 4 hosts editors. You can run the below script on all 4 host editors to apply changes to all useres on all hosts

- Step-1: Set Execution policy to Remote Signed using
  `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
- Step-2: Run this command on all host editord `cd c:\Temp'| Out-File -FilePath $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts -Force`

[image]

- Step-3: Now close all 4 editors and open again. You should see the
  Prompt changes to `PS C:\Temp>` on all 4 editors

[image]

- Step-4. Now log-off and sign in as different user on that pc and
  again open all 4 host editors
- Step-5 You should see that prompt changes again to `PS C:\Temp>`

[image]

Note: If you have installed both `32bit` & `64bit` version of host then script will work on only that version of  editor on which you originally created the profile script for. Example you can see that profile script din't run for
different version of host editor

[image]